# HTML Tabbed Control

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm looking at creating some software using html (and whatever else would help). I'm new to this but I do know some of the UI elements I would need. I've tried some other UI items (ex. buttons) with success, but can't get a tabbed control. I've downloaded a few samples now, but they all seem to behave poorly in that the tabbed control doesn't show but instead shows the tabs as links and then the content inside the tabs come after all the links are shown. Nothing like the sample in the demos.

I'm certain this is due to some basic knowledge that is unsaid in the demos, but what exactly I have no idea. I assumed I could just copy the code into a local file and then load it into my browser. Probably a bad assumption.

Here's some code that doesn't work that I downloaded, if that helps, but feel free to suggest another site that will either work "as is" or explain what I need to set up for this to work. I'm currently just investigating if this is feasible and reasonable to do. I'm trying to gauge how difficult this would be to do to decide if I should go further down this path.

thx.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Content via Ajax</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
                ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                    ui.panel.html(
                        "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                        "If this wouldn't be a demo.");
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Preloaded 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>1: Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. 

Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna 

quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius 

sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>2: Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. 

Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna 

quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius 

sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the missing `http:` from your jQuery references and stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: The missing protocol field (`http:`) is not required. If it's omitted the browser will use the same protocol as was used to fetch the page.

Comment: Actually they are not missing. It is refereed to as protocol agnostic urls, you can read more information about it from [@paul-irish](http://stackoverflow.com/users/89484/paul-irish) here: http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: This is true if the file is accessed through a web server, but it is NOT true if you are opening the file directly from the file system.  Since he is "new at this" is is likely he is just playing around with some HTML without bothering to set up a web server yet.  It's trying to load the references with file://.